# Adding the MainMenu to Joomla 1.6 Template

Tags: joomla-template

I tried to install some free Template from the Joomla 1.6 CMS. 
Every Template (and every tutorial) i downloaded cannot show the main Menu on the left site.

There are this Lines in index.php file:

```
  <?php if($this->countModules('left')) : ?>
  <div id="sidebar" class="grid_<?php echo $leftcolgrid;?>">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="left"style="xhtml" />
  </div>
  <?php endif; ?>
```

How can i set up to show the Main-Menu on the left site for Joomla 1.6?

Comment: Another Note, if this is your actual main menu, you should label the module mainnav or something like that. if this is just a duplication, your fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not have much experience in 1.6 but in 1.5 the PHP code has really nothing to do with it. it all depends on where you positioned the module that contains the main menu.

so do this:

1. Go to admin panel Extensions > Module Manager.
2. Look for main menu, you should see the position in the table. if it does not say left then go into it and select left. Save.
3. If it does say left for position, go in and make sure you have selected the correct menu to reference in the right column. it's under Basic options.

Another thing to check in firebug(if you don't have it, get it. it's almost a standard.) but make sure in fire bug that your div#sidebar is showing up, if not then there is a problem with your if statement.

Hope this helps.